# How to choose inner xml tag when serializing a list<string>?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, tags

I think I already did that once upon a time, but I can't get it to work...

I've got a class that contains a variable

```
List<string> InputList;
```

When serialized, it's obviously like:

```
<InputList>
    <string>foo</string>
    <string>bar</string>
</InputList>
```

And, call me a control freak, but I want:

```
<InputList>
    <Input>foo</Input>
    <Input>bar</Input>
</InputList>
```

I think there's a kind of [metadata] info I can put above my variable to get that, but what's the syntax, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[XmlArray("InputList")]
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName="Input")]
public List<string> InputList { get; set; }
```

Or if you *just* want the `<Input>` elements (no `<InputList>`)

```
[XmlElement("Input")]
public List<string> InputList { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I wanted. I guess if I should ass a 'dear lazyweb' tag to this question ;o)